# AWS S3 Static Website Push Capability

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-iot

Is there a way for me to have a static website on S3 that uses lambda and api gateway for services but to have messages pushed from lambda (that originated from a scheduled run) instead of polling for new information?

I was thinking of using IOT, but im not too familiar with it im not sure if a website can be a IOT thing, the documentation doesnt really help much with configuring your things.

Any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What is your usecase?

Comment: You are able to use IoT for it. A nice article can be found here: [How To Build A Serverless Notification System on AWS](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-notifications-on-aws/)

Comment: Thanks MaiKay that looks exactly like what I was thinking, will give that a shot

Answer (score 0):

Answer from MaiKay looks like exactly what i wanted to achieve, blog post even has a small demo where messages can be pushed to a session running in another tab:

> You are able to use IoT for it. A nice article can be found here: https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-notifications-on-aws – MaiKaY